# How to make tab key work in C++ Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox

I am a noob for C++ Win32 API. I am trying to make a textbox (edit control). In the textbox, I want to make the tab key act as it would in notepad, i.e., it would advance the cursor to the next tab stop in a textbox. I made a simple edit control with some scrollbars, auto-scrolling and multiline styles. I want the tab key to advance the cursor to the next tab stop. But it doesn't happen. The tab key doesn't do anything, literally nothing. It acts as if it wasn't assigned to do any task inside an edit control.

If anyone knows how to do that, I would be really grateful to him.

Here's the full code which I used for creating an edit control :-

```
HWND hTb = CreateWindow
(
    L"Edit", L"LOL",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_WANTRETURN | WS_TABSTOP,
    0, 0, LOWORD (lp), HIWORD (lp),
    hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
);
```

I am creating `hTb` in the `WM_CREATE` message of the `WndProc`. This edit control is just used for resizing it and nothing complicated. Here's the code :-

```
case WM_SIZE :
{
    MoveWindow (hTb, 0, 0, LOWORD (lp), HIWORD (lp), TRUE);
    break;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Innocuous as this may appear, that's a fairly advanced topic. You're going to have to [subclass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) your edit control, and handle the [WM_GETDLGCODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-getdlgcode) message to delegate `VK_TAB` handling to the parent window.

Comment: @IInspectable I think you mean "handle the `WM_GETDLGCODE` message to **return `DLGC_WANTTAB`**". The OP wants the edit control to handle the tab key as text input, not send it to the parent window, such as for navigating between controls.

Comment: Indeed. That only makes it harder, since now you also need to implement custom rendering of the text.

Comment: @IInspectable the multiline edit control can render tabs just fine.

Comment: @HitarthPadaliya I tested that the multi-line text box can use the TAB button normally. Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). (Please note: delete your private information)

Comment: I am putting the following code in the `WM_CREATE` message of the `WndProc` :-



`HWND hTb = CreateWindow
(
 L"Edit", L"LOL",

 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_WANTRETURN,

 0, 0, LOWORD (lp), HIWORD (lp),

 hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL

);`

Comment: @HitarthPadaliya I also tested it and it worked for me. Is there any other code that affects this window?

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT it is just the resizing code here :-

`case WM_SIZE :
{
 MoveWindow (hTb, 0, 0, LOWORD (lp), HIWORD (lp), TRUE);
 break;
}`

Comment: Does it work when you use TAB in Notepad?

Comment: @HitarthPadaliya do you actually need "dialog manager" functionality? e.g. tabbing between controls, because I am guessing you have an IsDialogMessage() in your message loop. If you take that out the edit control will receive tabs and treat them as text

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT Yeah in notepad, it works like charm.

Comment: @jwezorek I don't want to tab between controls. I just want a simple big textbox like the one in notepad. Also I am using that in a window based application. I don't currently want any dialogs.

Comment: @HitarthPadaliya does your message loop have IsDialogMessage() in it?

Comment: @jwezorek Yeah I have IsDialogMessage () in my message loop.

Comment: @HitarthPadaliya take that out and your problem will go away

Comment: @jwezorek Yes it works perfectly as wanted without the IsDialogMessage () in the message loop. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add SOLVED to the question title or to edit the solution into the question. If you found a solution you want to share, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If someone else provided an answer that solves the problem, you can indicate that by clicking the checkmark next to the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit controls will not receive tabs if "the dialog manager" portion of Win32 is engaged. For a modeless dialog box, the way you will see dialog box semantics showing up in a window is if the application's main message loop is filtering messages with the API call `IsDialogMessage`. `IsDialogMessage` will reroute tab presses to the window rather than the focused control, in this case the edit box.

To fix the problem use a standard message loop. That is,

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}
```

not

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if (!IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

You can read more about the dialog manager on Raymond Chen's blog: [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050329-00/?p=36043), [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050330-00/?p=36023), and [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120416-00/?p=7853)